# If criteria met, add new row above specif text. How to change color of that row?

Tags: excel, vba

Need to color the new row added by the below code. Cannot get a code to do it, can you please help?

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim LstRw As Long, x

Set sh = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")

With sh
    LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = LstRw To 2 Step -1
          If .Cells(x, 1) Like "Customer account" Then
               .Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Insert
          End If
    Next x
End With
```

Comment: If the `x` row is shifted down, then `.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow` refers to the newly inserted row, which you can then color.

Comment: Do i write the code to color in the line that creates the new row? Tried and didn't work

Comment: Just below that one =)

Comment: Thank you, works good now. :)